# Django <div>{% block content %}

Tags: html, css, django

This is probably a silly question, but can you put a `<div>` stage around Django's `{% block content %}`?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Title</title>
        {% load static %}
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'property/style.css' %}">
        {% block head %}
        {% endblock %}
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class = "row">
            <div class = "column left">
                {% block left %}
                {% endblock %}
            </div>
            <div class = "column center">
                {% block center %}
                {% endblock %}
            <div class = "column right">
                {% block right %}
                {% endblock %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
<HTML>
```

and my CSS

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
    color: var(--text_color);
    background-color: var(--background_color);
    font-family: var(--font);
    font-size: var(--font_size);
}
.column {
    float: left;
    padding: var(--padding);
    height: 300px;
}
.left, .right {
    width: 25%;
}

.center {
    width: 50%;
}
.row:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
```

I am trying to make each `{% block %}` be a column without having to write the `<div>` for each template. However, my HTML output is stacking them on top of each other instead of side by side. [image]

**edit: Post the rendererd HTML document, so we know what Django has done to it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can do that... But your problem is that a ending `</div>` tag is missing:

```
<div class = "row">
    <div class = "column left">
        {% block left %}
        {% endblock %}
    </div>
    <div class = "column center">
        {% block center %}
        {% endblock %}
    </div>
    <div class = "column right">
        {% block right %}
        {% endblock %}
    </div>
</div>
```

Checkout this structure.

Comment: No luck changing that. The text still stacks up on top of each other

Comment: In my experience with css and float, you don't have to use 25%, 50% and 25% in width property. Why 'cause you have margin and padding that is added to the relative width so you have to manage those pixeles and dont use the 100% of the width.